# Ubuntu 18.04 succesfull install, failed reboot

Tags: reboot

Installed ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 10. Acter succesfull install i was prompted to "restart now".
This is the error that i got (typing it down if image won't upload):
INFO: task Xorg:1493 blocked for more than 120seconds.
Not tainted 4.15.0-29generic #31 ubuntu
"Echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

How to fix this? And what is the cause?

Comment: Do you have Nvidia video hardware?  If so, you need the word "nomodeset" onto the grub line (type e to edit, instructions at bottom of page), and add nomodeset at the "quiet splash" words.  Add the proprietary Nvidua drivers to avoid this at first boot.

Comment: Added nomodest where you said. Laptop booted up. Changed additional drivers to use nvidia-driver-390. Now the resolution is 800x600 can't change it in display menu it says unknown dislpay

Comment: To solve your problem ,try searching this site for  Ubuntu stuck in low resolution   lots of hits.